# The formation of black holes and their destiny

Tags: black-holes

Is anyone else against the current theory on what occurs for a black hole to begin? I know a black hole occurs due to neutron degeneracy no longer creating contraction energy to combat the hydrostatic equilibrium, but after the density is so extreme that the black hole is created, I do not necessarily agree that "physics breaks down" as some physicists and astronomers claim, because I do not agree that spacetime bends infinitely with infinitesimal volume. Quantum mechanics and relativity do not make sense when quantifying and qualifying a black hole but I do not think that its error is the answer, I think there must be a connection with the multi-verse theory which suggests black holes as umbilical cords between universes. What do you guys think about this?

Comment: Hi imo what you say in your last line "could" be true, but finding experimental proof of any connection between multi-universes and black holes would be difficult. The multi-verse is not a theory as such, just a hypothesis,  as we lack any proof to date. Open to correction on this tho, i'm no expert  Regards

Comment: _neutron degeneracy no longer creating contraction energy_   again, I'm no expert but I'm not sure this bit makes physical sense, no offence intended. When a star is at this stage, is there really any more "contraction" energy left to provide, it's contracted as much as it can. Again, an answer below would teach me a lot  regards

Comment: No offense taken. It actually does make sense, as neutron degeneracy happens because protons and electrons collide to form neutrons at an extreme density and release contraction energy. Degenerate gas pressure is only dependent on density which is why the gravitational contraction keeps happening thus not letting the star expand.

Comment: Thank you very much , I learned from that,the comments are much better for me than answers at my level of knowledge, my wrong assumption was that the neutrons had already formed best regards

Comment: "Neutron degenercy" I think you're referring to a neutron star whereby matters collapse inwards due to strong gravitational pull but is prevented from further collapse into a black hole due to pep, all depends on the mass of the star. In a dying star heavy particle like neutron is concentrated in its core until the star burnt out. Black hole is a door to multiverse you say, I don't know perhaps you're referring to wormholes. I don't know if our universe is a membrane or bubble or others. Chill let's drink up.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what the astronomers claim? "Physics breaks down" means that our theories give nonsensical answers, which means that we need new ones. I don't understand what the question is about...

Comment: User6770 I refer to neutron degeneracy as I explained, this is the phase of stellar evolution that occurs from supergiant stars collapsing into a type II supernova leaving a remnant of a black hole if degenerate or neutron star if not. I do not refer to wormholes I know what they are, nevertheless, where do you think wormholes lead to? It's a rip through spacetime's fabric, therefore a wormhole would lead you to another universe as well, just a matter of where-which is impossible to know (for us and our mathematics), however the quantum foam, wormholes and black holes are similar but differing

Comment: in its structure and dynamics.

Comment: Martin, That is true, however it is also said that physics breaks down because the mathematics we have are not enough to explain them which implies that physics fails to go any further. I believe that physics doesn't break down, it simply requires further advance of our mathematical knowledge and intuition which we possibly will not go through for more decades to come. Perhaps more. The question (as stated various  times) is what you believe about the current theory, do you agree with it? Disagree? Please reply to this question if you must.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that can be answered within our current understanding of physics, since GR and QFT fail at predicting what exists beyond the event horizon of a black hole. Philosophically, the question you ask is fascinating, because it represents one of the deepest mysteries in physics. In practice, though, we are only really concerned with things that can be observed. The existence of objects too dense to be anything besides a black hole is well supported by observations of SMBHs. The existence of an event horizon is well supported by observations of the spectra of accretion disks around stellar mass black holes. Whatever really happens beyond the event horizon is a mystery for the future, but at the present the canonical model for black holes explains everything we have seen to date, so

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to know if you agreed that the theory posed as of now does not make sense. Without getting philosophical that it does not make sense because we cannot grasp it, I am simply stating that it does not make sense because apart from it being a theory from the "infinite" answers obtained using QM and GR, it doesn't make sense that there could be an infinite mass with close to 0 volume since other ideas of spacetime indicate spacetime behaving differently as it would with a black hole. I believe that multiverse is a theory because it is a concept that is proven to many.

Comment: The idea that ripples of gravity were observed last year and that the universe as we know it functions by ways of spontaneity, it makes no sense believing that something spontaneous like the Big Bang cannot occur more than once.